# Is there a branch of geometry that considers complex coordinates?

Tags: differential-geometry

As shown in the title, is there such a kind of geometry that considers complex coordinates?

For example, a geometry that involves a metric tensor which is a $2\times2$ complex matrix and the corresponding  coordinates a pair of complex numbers?

Comment: [complex-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-geometry)

Comment: You might want to look at Pedoe's beautiful book *Geometry: A Comprehensive Course*.

Comment: Ahh, thanks! Do you have other good books for recommendation?

Comment: I do not know how advanced you are. There are all sorts of books on complex manifolds and complex differential geometry, but I was assuming you were looking for something more elementary.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Hi, I am familiar with real differential geometry. And I want to learn some complex differential geometry. I would like those books that are complete and rigorous and not just for beginners or physicists.

Comment: Look at Huybrechts, Griffiths & Harris, Chern (*Complex Manifolds without Potential Theory*).